# sort the displayed grid in descending order using extjs 6.2

Tags: sorting, extjs

for context, i'm trying to redirect the view after clicking the save button. so im invoking the function "redirectToJobRequestPanel" once save is successful. It updates the view but i'm not able to sort it programmatically. i'm trying to sort the list to descending order but i'm not able to do so after so many trial and error. here is my current implementation, i removed the panel and added an new one as a context object. I want to sort the column "id" by descending order and hopefully the rest of the columns will follow:

```
redirectToJobRequestPanel: function() {
    console.log('redirectToJobRequestPanel called');
    
    let mainContentPanel = Ext.getCmp('main-content-panel');
           
    mainContentPanel.removeAll();
          
    // Add the requested jobs panel as the new content panel
    mainContentPanel.add({
        xtype: 'requestedjobsmain'
    });
    
    this.setActiveMainNavTreeSelection();
    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your Store. You need to find the store you're using in your grid and sort it like this: store.sort('id', 'DESC');

Comment: i tried this code and it worked, however the delay is fixed with 150milliseconds because the sort only works after the store has been loaded. is there away sort it without giving a fixed time because the loading of the store varies depending on the internet speed right:

        Ext.defer(function() {
            let store = requestedJobsGridPanel.getStore();
            store.sort('id', 'DESC');
            },150
        );

Comment: Did you try adding a sorter to the store  to avoid calling the sort method?
https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-sorters

Comment: You can try to add luck directly in your viewModel.

  stores: {
    mystore:{
      ...
      sorters: [{
        property: 'id',
        direction: 'DESC'
      }]
    }
  }